# Как правильно отрефакторить код?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, рефакторинг

Как правильно отрефакторить следующий код?

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    })
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: "template/home.html",
            controller: "homeCtrl"
        })
        .when('/artist', {
            templateUrl: "template/artist.html",
            controller: "artistCtrl"
        })
        .when('/:collectionId', {
            templateUrl: "template/template.html",
            controller: "templateCtrl"
        })
        .when('/:trackId', {
            templateUrl: "template/template1.html",
            controller: "templateCtrl"
        })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    })


}]);
```

Выходит, что получить могу только шаблон `template.html` а `template1.html` не могу

Comment: а чем отличается `trackId` от `collectionId`?

Comment: Это id двух разных обьектов

Comment: Как отличить что к какому маршруту должен относиться путь `/1`?

Comment: если ты сам нашел ответ - стоит добавить его как свой собственный ответ. Либо просто удалить вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: "template/home.html",
            controller: "homeCtrl"
        })
        .when('/artist', {
            templateUrl: "template/artist.html",
            controller: "artistCtrl"
        })
        .when('/album/:collectionId', {
            templateUrl: "template/album.html",
            controller: "albumCtrl"
        })
        .when('/video/:trackId', {
            templateUrl: "template/videoTemplate.html",
            controller: "videoTemplateCtrl"
        })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    })


}]);
```

Comment: добавь описание в чем была проблема и что сделал для решения